# Why is the default value of WHOAMI register of MPU9250 is 0x71?

Tags: microcontroller, robotics, mpu6050

I'm reading the datasheet of MPU9250 and I find out the address of MPU6050 inside MPU9250 is b110100x. But when I see the description of WHOAMI register, it says the default value is 0x71. And I cannot figure out any relationship between b110100x and 0x71.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Thank you～

BTW why does everyone put 0 in front of the address and say that the address of MPU9250 is 0x68? It seems more sense to put 0 on the LSB since that LSB represent read or write.

Comment: What is `b110100x` even supposed to mean? 6 bits + dont care? 7 bits? Why not 8 bits?

Comment: Those two values don't have anything to do with each other. 0b110100x is the I2C address (with lower bit selected by the AD0 pin), the other is just a value identifying the device. They aren't related concepts.

Comment: As for the last part, `0x` is a prefix for a hexadecimal value, like `0b` is one for a binary value. The leading `0` and `x` aren't a part of the value. `0x68` can be otherwise written as `68h`.

Comment: Unless you're asking why it's `0x68` instead of `0xD0`. In that case, it's the difference between the 7-bit address and the full byte that denotes address+read/write which are `0xD0` and `0xD1`.

Comment: @ThomasJager Yeah `0xD0` is what I mean! I just think it is really confusing to shift the address right to become `0x68`...
Thank you for you explaining~~ I never thought that address and number will be indepent!